# How do I interpret the results of gpscat?

Tags: embedded, output, gpsd

I've been trying to get gps data from an embedded system. This is the command I use:

```
gpscat /dev/ttyS2
```

And I get a continuous stream of output like this:

> $GLGSV,1,1,03,70,14,098.6102,E,121853.000,A,A*50
>   $GPRMC,121853.000,A,59480,N,00604.6102,E,AA,10,1.0,203.6,47.6,,*64
>   $04.6102,E,121854.000,A,A*57
>   $GPRMC,121854.000,A$GPGSV,2,1,08,05,11,032,40,16,55,300,14,18,17,14GLL,5046.9480,N,00604.6102,E,121855.000,A,A*56
>   +GPSPVT:0,12:18:57,17/07/2017,3D FIX,N 050 46'5604.6102,E,121857.000,A,A*54
>   $GPRMC,121857.000,A6,35,20,31,075,35*7D
>   $GPGSV,2,2,08,21,74,133,29GLL,5046.9480,N,00604.6102,E,121858.000,A,A*5B
>   *59 $GLGSA,A,3,70,85,,,,,,,,,,,,,,1.0,*25 $GNGGLL,5046.9480,N,00604.6102,E,121859.000,A,A*5A
>   ,16,18,20,21,26,29,31,,,,,1.6,1.0,1.2*2E
>   $GNGSA5046.9480,N,00604.6102,E,0.0,321.6,170717,,,A*61.88",E 006
>   04'36.61",+0203m
>   $GPVTG,321.6,T,,M,0GLL,5046.9480,N,00604.6102,E,121903.000,A,A*54
>   ,031,40,16,56,299,17,18,19,145,35,20,31,074,35*74.6102,E,121904.000,A,A*53
>   $GPRMC,121904.000,A,,080,37,31,16,203,21*7E
>   $GLGSV,1,1,03,70,15,09704.6102,E,121905.000,A,A*52
>   $GPRMC,121905.000,A8,05,10,031,40,16,56,299,18,18,19,145,35,20,31,0,*62
>   $GNGSA,A,3,05,16,18,20,21,26,29,31,,,,,1.6.88",E 006 04'36.61",+0203m
>   $GPGGA,12

Can you explain how I would interpret this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read about NMEA protocol its raw of them,  details [here](http://www.gpsinformation.org/dale/nmea.htm), and [here](http://navspark.mybigcommerce.com/content/NMEA_Format_v0.1.pdf).

each line is frame of protocol:
$GPRMC,123519,A,4807.038,N,01131.000,E,022.4,084.4,230394,003.1,W*6A

Where:

```
 RMC          Recommended Minimum sentence C
 123519       Fix taken at 12:35:19 UTC
 A            Status A=active or V=Void.
 4807.038,N   Latitude 48 deg 07.038' N
 01131.000,E  Longitude 11 deg 31.000' E
 022.4        Speed over the ground in knots
 084.4        Track angle in degrees True
 230394       Date - 23rd of March 1994
 003.1,W      Magnetic Variation
 *6A          The checksum data, always begins with *
```

Note that, as of the 2.3 release of NMEA, there is a new field

Comment: GPRMC is what I need, but why does the format of the output keep changing as you can see?

Comment: format is still the same, but not all data are sended each time, see blank field (, is separator)

Comment: The , separator doesn't seem consistent. It should be this format: "GPRMC, 123519, A, 4807.038, N, 01131.000, E...."  But for my sample output: "GPRMC,121905.000,A8,05,10,031,40,16,56,299,18,18,19,145,35,20,31,0,*62", There is no N and also no comma indicating where it should be. I can't figure out where the longitude is at or where it should be if it was omitted.

Comment: If I am understanding this correctly: GPRMC,121905.000,A8,05,10,031,40,16,56,299,18,18,19,145,35,20,31,0,*62 -> "121905.000" is Fix, "A8" is status??, and "05" is latitutde, but there is no "N" and also no ",(blank)," that indicates N is missing

Comment: A8 Q7 s WIRED, maybe its transmision error, you need to check checksum first, before analyze data

Comment: But how would I get the original output to compare the checksum against?

Comment: You need to calculate checksum from preamble ($) and checksum marker (*) and compare to this from packet. see [packet]
(https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/GPS/Modules/PMTK_Protocol.pdf) format.

Comment: Ok, but currently the output means that there is a data transmission problem right? it should never be like this? Here is a new line of output I got: $GPRMC,130359.000,A,,283,15,29,10,091,39*7B, the "degree, E" is now missing on this one.

Comment: I think there was some problem with transmission, because checksum is incorrect based on it: http://siliconsparrow.com/demos/nmeachecksum.php but I'm not sure, I have doing something like that few years ago, and didn't remember how it was going

Comment: What should it be? I'm getting 30.